# Can Azure/AWS services replace spring cloud and Netflix features?

Tags: spring, azure, cloud, microservices

I am architecting a Java microservices middleware that will be deployed in a cloud computing provider (Azure, most likely). The tech stack I am considering is made up of the following frameworks/libraries (databases not included):
-Spring
-Spring Cloud
-Spring Cloud Config Server
-Spring Cloud Sleuth
-Netflix Ribbon
-Netflix Eureka
-Netflix Zuul
-Netflix Hystrix
-Kafka Apache

My question is if it's possible to avoid using the Spring Cloud packages family, along with the Netflix ones, and replace their functionality with the services available in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a suite of services behind a Zuul gateway & Eureka discovery service which work great when deployed using docker-compose.

Moving to Azure I created a new Kubernetes cluster and can deploy my services... but I'm having to rethink the gateway strategy.  I *think* that you/I need to setup/run an Azure Application Gateway / Load Balancer.  I found the steps here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/quick-create-portal

It appears that the cost of the Gateway is one of the more expensive services.

Comment: so is it possible to deploy spring microservices in Azure or AWS without using Spring Cloud and Netflix Eureka, and the rest of libraries that go with them?

Comment: Yes.  Azure provides their own discovery / gateway tools.  As far as I can tell, if you're using AKS (Azure Kubernetes) you have to use the Azure tools.